# Why is my question not considered to be about Gameplay strategies and tactics?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions

Why is [my question here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/323552/199241) *not* considered to be about [Gameplay strategies and tactics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or any kind that is on topic for that matter?

Comment: A question being closed as off topic doesn't mean it was off-topic. It means that 5 users wanted to close it. There's a difference.

Comment: You have my reopen vote anyway.

Comment: @Studoku Well, thanks. At least now I know it's not exactly black and white.

Answer (score 5):

You mentioned, and even included a link to, a third party tool. When including such media, a lot of users will see that as either promoting that media or asking how to use that media. Simply doing this is enough to get users to close your question because it's a legit way to close a question.

The other part of your question that doesn't help at all is that it is very broad. We can't encompass ALL heroes in ALL pick/ban situations, there are just far too many of them. You need to narrow down what you are asking - pinpoint something such as "Should I target supports or assassins in the early stages of pick/ban".

Essentially what you need to do is change the wording of your question. If you get rid of the link to the third party info, narrow down your pick/ban question to something a little more specific, you'll have a good question.

Comment: I disagree with the second part completely. One uses their own drafting algorithm each time they're the leader, be it: "pick/ban random" or not. It may be broad a player answers that same question in up to 5 and a half minutes.

Comment: I, however, think you may be right about the third-party tool part. I did update the question accordingly.

Comment: @Nae I know you think it's not broad, but it kind of is. The only legit answer that can help with "the algorithm part" of your question is: If the enemy drafts hero A, look to ban heroes X, Y, Z because of -these- known synergies. Going into that length of detail is usually marked as "broad" for Arqade questions. That's why Frank had said it's too broad for a detailed and acceptable answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think this question in its current state is incredibly broad and nearly impossible to answer meaningfully.  I think this question should not be reopened without further editing.

However, **I don't think the question should've been closed in the first place.**

In its original form, this was a question about using a "Game-specific...utilit[y]", which is explicitly allowed in [the help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).